# how can internal energy do work?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

how can internal energy do work? As far as i know, internal energy is the sum of KE and PE. But how can this, in turn, do work? It would be great if you can give me some scenarios. Thank you.

Comment: The internal energy doesn't do work.  The gas does work, and, when it does so adiabatically, its internal energy decreases.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Mr.Miller, you as a PHD retired engineer surely has countless experiences dealing with internal energy and work. It would be very helpful if i can get an answer from you sir.

Comment: Well, in freshman physics, when you had moving block A colliding elastically with stationary block B, some of the momentum and kinetic energy from block A got transferred to block B, so the kinetic energy of block A decreased.  During the short time of the collision, there was a deformation of block B, and this is how block A  did work on block B.  So block A did work on block B, and its kinetic energy decreased.

Answer (score 2):

Take the example of system consisting of ideal gas and an insulated piston/cylinder so that no heat transfers occur.

The gas molecules have kinetic energy and are constantly impacting the piston. If the gas expands against the piston (displaces the piston) the gas does work (force times distance). The work is done at the expense of some of the kinetic energy of the gas molecules, that is, at the expense of some of the internal energy of the gas. Since the temperature of an ideal gas is a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the gas molecules, the temperature decreases.

Bottom line, the work done by the gas equals the decrease in the internal energy of the gas.

Hope this  helps.

Answer (score 0):

Internal energy arises from the energy of all its parts, or the atoms/molecules/electrons/whatever that compose it. If these particles have lots of energy on average, they can transfer this energy to something else.

For example, a hot gas has a large internal energy since the atoms have higher kinetic energies and velocities. If you put this hot gas in a balloon, it will expand the balloon since the high energy atoms will collide with the boundaries. In other words, the gas does work on the balloon by transferring the kinetic energy of its atoms (which all contribute to the internal energy).

Comment: how did the balloon have work done on it? I thought there must be a distance change on the balloon?

Comment: @Negrawh Work is force acting against a change in length scale. This can be pressure against a change in volume, force against a change in length, etc. Work is done on the balloon because it changes in size.